# Sublime Text 3 Build Python Code with virtualenv

Tags: python, sublimetext3, virtualenv

I am  trying to using sublime text 3 for python development with virtualenv!
I‘ve read the answer that i can find on Stackoverflow and baidu(our national search engine ),but i am still very confused. i hope you can help me,tank you very much！
My computer system：ubuntu 17.04
My sublime configuration file:

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "follow_symlinks": true,
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "build_systems":
    [
        {
          "name":"my_flask_env",
          "cmd":["python","-u","$file"],
          "path":"/myproject/venv/bin:$PATH",
          "file_regex":"^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
          "env":{
            "PYTHONIOENCODING":"utf8",
            "PYTHONHOME":"",
          },
          "selector": "source.python"
        }
    ]
}
```

the code of test.py:

```
import sys,os,flask
print(sys.executable)
#print(inspect.getsoutcefile(flask))
```

when i run test.py ,the error like this:

```
ImportError: No module named site
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['python', '-u', '/home/bole/myproject/flask_test/test.py']]
[dir: /home/bole/myproject/flask_test]
[path: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin]
```

So,What should I do now that it will work properly .

My English just so so,i hope it's clear.

Comment: Please do not add images, but report the full error. In your case, you need to install a module named site, which you can do using -- pip install site.

Comment: @Azrael  i have install the module named site ,but the error do not change at all .

Answer (score 0):

Using Terminus and Virtualenv in Sublime Text 3 can be easy. Virtualwrapper is installed and outside Sublime I am using 'workon myenv'. Workon can be used in a sublime-build.
My venv is called boringStuff.

```
{
  "target": "terminus_exec",
  "cancel": "terminus_cancel_build",

  "shell_cmd": "workon boringStuff;python3 -u \"$file\"",
  "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
  "working_dir": "$file_path",
  "selector": "source.python",
  "env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"},

}
```